# Slow responses and high timeouts retrieving SentEvent

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap

When retrieving SentEvents:

- A call requesting an hour of EventDates resulting in 196 events, takes 8-9 seconds to receive a response
- A call requesting 24 hours of EventDates resulting in ~5000 events (I assume), fails to receive a response and times out, or varies in time to return between 2 and 12 minutes

**Steps to Reproduce**

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "SOAPAction: Retrieve" -d "$(cat xmlrequest.txt)" "https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx"
```

Where the body of xmlrequest.txt is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username>A_VALID_USERNAME</Username>
        <Password>A_VALID_PASSWORD</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>SentEvent</ObjectType>
        <Properties>SendID</Properties>
        <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
          <Property>EventDate</Property>
          <SimpleOperator>between</SimpleOperator>
          <DateValue>2014-12-08T20:44:51</DateValue>
          <DateValue>2014-12-08T21:44:51</DateValue>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Is there any way I can optimize my request to reduce timeouts?

Comment: Time outs are probably going to happen for such a request... are you open to other means, like FTP or doing a Query Activity, and doing a SOAP call on the resulting data extension?

Comment: FTP probably wouldn't be suitable, as it looks like it wouldn't accept an automated call with criteria to generate the file. We'll look at the Query Activity documentation, though, and see if it'll suit our purpose. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to perform the SentEvent hourly, and set `RetrieveAllSinceLastBatch` to true.

```
  <Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>SentEvent</ObjectType>
        <Properties>SendID</Properties>
        <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
          <Property>EventDate</Property>
          <SimpleOperator>between</SimpleOperator>
          <DateValue>2014-12-08T20:44:51</DateValue>
          <DateValue>2014-12-08T21:44:51</DateValue>
        </Filter>
        <RetrieveAllSinceLastBatch>true</RetrieveAllSinceLastBatch>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </Body>
```

What this will do is grab everything that has processed in the last hour in the database. It may have started prior to that hour, but will only show up after processing.  This will ensure you get all the data you require, and run at a speed that is at least functional.